# GDI Printing In C# Memory Leak Woes, Unexplained Errors, Inability to thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, printing, memory-leaks, gdi

We are using Win32 calls to the GDI Printing API to print graphics.

I've noticed that on certain PCL print queues, we leak GDI memory when printing. As far as I can tell everything is being disposed of properly. Not being an admin at my company it's rather difficult for me to tell which drivers print queues are using. PCL6 drivers appear to be the main culprit. Other seemingly unrelated issues I've seen:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The data area passed to a system call is too small
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully

```
var hdc = GdiPrintWin32.CreateDC(IntPtr.Zero, printerName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
if (hdc == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw GetError("Device context failed for {0}", printerName);

try
{
    if (GdiPrintWin32.StartDoc(hdc, ref doc) <= 0)
        throw GetError("Failed to start print job");
```

This logic is currently being done in a WCF hosted inside a Windows service. When I set the instance mode to single and hammer it, I only get it the first couple calls; when I set the instance mode to per call, it's a lot easier to reproduce.

I've also seen errors where basically no calls can go through to the service for about 20 minutes and requires a restart to fix. I notice that after stopping the service there are Windows Event logs to the effect of:

> 2 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User...: Process 3792 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER... Process 3792 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe) has opened key ...\Software\Hewlett-Packard\HP SSNP

Basically it's been nothing but a nightmare for us. Has anyone had any experience with anything like this?

The guts of the code we're using to print are:

```
var doc = new Docinfo { DocName = printJobName };

// create a device-context 
var hdc = GdiPrintWin32.CreateDC(IntPtr.Zero, printerName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
if (hdc == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw GetError("Device context failed for {0}", printerName);

try
{
    if (GdiPrintWin32.StartDoc(hdc, ref doc) <= 0)
        throw GetError("Failed to start print job");


    foreach (PrintingMetafile metafile in pages)
    {
        var bytes = metafile.GetBytes();

        // load the bytes to a memory location and get the pointer
        var inMemRef = GdiPrintWin32.SetEnhMetaFileBits((uint)bytes.Length, bytes);

        if (inMemRef == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw GetError("Failed to create EMF in memory");

        // Get the pixel coordinates of the paper
        var x = 0; // GdiPrintWin32.GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZSIZE);
        var y = 0; // GdiPrintWin32.GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTSIZE);
        var hres = GdiPrintWin32.GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);
        var vres = GdiPrintWin32.GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES);

        var rect = new Rect { Left = x, Top = y, Right = hres, Bottom = vres };

        if (GdiPrintWin32.StartPage(hdc) <= 0)
            throw GetError("StartPage failed");


        if (GdiPrintWin32.PlayEnhMetaFile(hdc, inMemRef, ref rect) == 0)
            throw GetError("PlayEnhMetaFile failed");

        if (GdiPrintWin32.EndPage(hdc) <= 0)
            throw GetError("EndPage failed");


        if (inMemRef != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            GdiPrintWin32.DeleteEnhMetaFile(inMemRef);
        }
    }

    if (GdiPrintWin32.EndDoc(hdc) <= 0)
        throw GetError("Failed to finish print job");
}
finally
{
    GdiPrintWin32.DeleteDC(hdc);
}
```

Comment: Microsoft strongly discourages printing from a service.  Printer drivers just are not written to operate correctly from session 0.  Like they'll nag you to buy more toner and you'll never know it.  HP has also imploded badly, their drivers just suck.

Comment: What is the type of the return from `GdiPrintWin32.CreateDC`? Does that type implement IDisposable?

Comment: @JohnSaunders We're calling unmanaged code here, using pinvoke. None of this code implements IDisposable.

Comment: I  meant, in that case, do the equivalent.

Comment: @HansPassant do you have any links specifically pointing out the gdi32 library is not meant to be used from a service? Or is this just personal experience? There really is no good managed way to print from a windows service but I was under the impression this should be a feasible solution.